# Iterate over a changing list length and append to another list

Tags: python, list

I want to iterate over a beautifulsoup object that changes length based on the number of elements it finds matching the HTML tag.

```
driver.get('https://www.inspection.gc.ca/food-recall-warnings-and-allergy-alerts/2021-02-10/eng/1613010591343/1613010596418')
page_source = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
recall_details = soup.find('table', class_ = 'table table-bordered table-condensed')

recalled_products = recall_details.find_all('td')
recalled_products
```

Output:

```
[<td>One Ocean</td>,
 <td>Sliced Smoked  Wild Sockeye Salmon</td>,
 <td>300 g</td>,
 <td>6 25984 00005 3</td>,
 <td>11253</td>]
```

I want to iterate over each td element and append to a list like this:

```
brands = []
products = []
sizes = []
upcs = []
codes = []

brand = recalled_products[0].text
product = recalled_products[1].text
size = recalled_products[2].text
upc = recalled_products[3].text
code = recalled_products[4].text
brands.append(brand)
products.append(product)
sizes.append(size)
upcs.append(upc)
codes.append(code)

print(brands)
print(products)
print(sizes)
print(upcs)
print(codes)
```

Output:

```
['One Ocean']
['Sliced Smoked  Wild Sockeye Salmon']
['300\xa0g']
['6\xa025984\xa000005\xa03']
['11253']
```

I tried the following code, but I am not getting the expected result. I need some kind of counter I think.

````
for i in range(len(recalled_products)):
    brand = recalled_products[i].text
    product = recalled_products[i].text
    size = recalled_products[i].text
    upc = recalled_products[i].text
    code = recalled_products[i].text
    brands.append(brand)
    products.append(product)
    sizes.append(size)
    upcs.append(upc)
    codes.append(code)

print(brands)
print(products)
print(sizes)
print(upcs)
print(codes)
```

Output:

```
['One Ocean', 'Sliced Smoked  Wild Sockeye Salmon', '300\xa0g', '6\xa025984\xa000005\xa03', '11253']
['One Ocean', 'Sliced Smoked  Wild Sockeye Salmon', '300\xa0g', '6\xa025984\xa000005\xa03', '11253']
['One Ocean', 'Sliced Smoked  Wild Sockeye Salmon', '300\xa0g', '6\xa025984\xa000005\xa03', '11253']
['One Ocean', 'Sliced Smoked  Wild Sockeye Salmon', '300\xa0g', '6\xa025984\xa000005\xa03', '11253']
['One Ocean', 'Sliced Smoked  Wild Sockeye Salmon', '300\xa0g', '6\xa025984\xa000005\xa03', '11253']
````

This is a sample html code of the website
[image]

Thank you in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Could you provide an example webpage or markup from it? If there is a parent element that contains the 5 fields you care about it would be easier to structure the data.

Comment: I updated the question and provided a sample HTML code of the website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would grab the markup.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = "https://www.inspection.gc.ca/food-recall-warnings-and-allergy-alerts/2021-02-10/eng/1613010591343/1613010596418"

brands = []
products = []
sizes = []
upcs = []
codes = []

page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

recall_details = soup.find("table", class_="table table-bordered table-condensed")

body = recall_details.find("tbody")

rows = body.find_all("tr")

for row in rows:
    data = row.find_all("td")
    brands.append(data[0].text)
    products.append(data[1].text)
    sizes.append(data[2].text)
    upcs.append(data[3].text)
    codes.append(data[4].text)
```

prints

```shell
['One Ocean']
['Sliced Smoked  Wild Sockeye Salmon']
['300\xa0g']
['6\xa025984\xa000005\xa03']
['11253']
```

---

I do think that a dict would be a better data structure than multiple lists, but of course that varies on your use case.

If you wanted to do that you could change the code like this:

```py
recalled = []

...

for row in rows:
    data = row.find_all("td")
    item = {
        "brand": data[0].text,
        "products": data[1].text,
        "sizes": data[2].text,
        "upcs": data[3].text,
        "codes": data[4].text,
    }
    recalled.append(item)
```

prints

```shell
[{'brand': 'One Ocean', 'products': 'Sliced Smoked  Wild Sockeye Salmon', 'sizes': '300\xa0g', 'upcs': '6\xa025984\xa000005\xa03', 'codes': '11253'}]
```

Comment: Thank you! Not exactly the answer I was looking for, but your code made me better understand BeatifulSoup.

Answer (score 2):

question on the data is the return from

```
recalled_products = recall_details.find_all('td') 

A = [[<td>beef</td>,
     <td>250g</td>,
     <td>6 25984 00005 3</td>,
     <td>11253</td>],
     [<td>Salmon</td>,
     <td>300 g</td>,
     <td>6 25984 00005 3</td>,
     <td>11253</td>]]
```

or

```
b = [<td>beef</td>,
     <td>250g</td>,
     <td>6 25984 00005 3</td>,
     <td>11253</td>,
     <td>Salmon</td>,
     <td>300 g</td>,
     <td>6 25984 00005 3</td>,
     <td>11253</td>]
```

for A you want to use indexing a 2D array

```
for i in range(len(recalled_products)):
    brand = recalled_products[i][0].text
    product = recalled_products[i][1].text
```

for B you want to use a step in your iteration

```
    for i in range(0,len(recalled_products),4):
      brand = recalled_products[i].text
      product = recalled_products[i+1].text
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work. The list (or better said, the beautifulsoup object) is a 1D array.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me as if you need to build a spreadsheet to hold the data that you need to store. You can use the library called [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to do this and then create columns for brands, products, sizes, upcs, codes.  Then store the results from your beautifulsoup object into the spreadsheet.